# GitLab: chosen stage does not exist

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to put together a fairly complex pipeline with several jobs that run sequentially in our different environments. This is to run our Terraform changes across our infra. The sequence of jobs should run automatically across our **infraci** environment which is only ever rolled out to via CI, then stop and require a button click to start the deployment to our **dev** environment which has actual (albeit dev) users. Of course I don't want to write the same code over and over again so I've tried to be as DRY as possible. Here is my **gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
---
# "variables" & "default" are used by all jobs
variables:
  TF_ROOT: '${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/terraform'
  TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE: .terraformrc
  AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS: regional
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-2
  ASG_MODULE_PATH: module.aws_asg.aws_autoscaling_group.main_asg

default:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint: ['']
  cache:
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform
  tags:
    - nonlive # This tag matches the group wide GitLab runner.
  before_script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}

# List of all stages (jobs within the same stage are executed concurrently)
stages:
  - init
  - infraci_plan
  - infraci_taint
  - infraci_apply
  - dev_plan
  - dev_taint
  - dev_apply

# "Hidden" jobs we use as templates to improve code reuse.
.default:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

.plan:
  extends: .default
  stage: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_plan
  script:
    - terraform workspace select ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    - terraform plan
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME != "infraci"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false

.taint:
  extends: .default
  stage: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_taint
  script: terrafrom taint ${ASG_MODULE_PATH}
  needs:
    - ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_plan

.apply:
  extends: .default
  stage: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_apply
  script: terraform apply -auto-approve

# Create actual jobs
## init - runs once per pipeline
init:
  stage: init
  script: terraform init
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: manual
  
## infraci - auto deploy
infraci_plan:
  extends: .plan
  environment:
    name: infraci

infraci_taint:
  extends: .taint
  environment:
    name: infraci

infraci_apply:
  extends: .apply
  environment:
    name: infraci

## dev - manual deployment
dev_plan:
  extends: .plan
  environment:
    name: dev

dev_taint:
  extends: .taint
  environment:
    name: dev

dev_apply:
  extends: .apply
  environment:
    name: dev
```

Unfortunately this fails validation with the following error:

```
infraci_plan job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, init, infraci_plan, infraci_taint, infraci_apply, dev_plan, dev_taint, dev_apply, .post
```

My assumption is that it's to do with interpolating `CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` in the hidden jobs but not actually setting the value until the jobs where the jobs are actually defined.

If that's the case though what's a way to get the setup I need without a severe amount of duplication?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is not possible to use a [variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) in `stage`. The only way I to see you need to define the stage directly in your job and remove the stage in `.plan`.

```
infraci_plan:
  extends: .plan
  stage: infraci_plan
  environment:
    name: infraci
```