# Error "sast job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are" for gitlab Static Application Security Testing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried following [these fairly simple instructions for integrating Static Application Security Testing (SAST)](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/12/16/mobile-static-application-security-testing-for-android/) into my Android CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab.  However, I got the following error when using the [CI lint tool](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html):

```
sast job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, stg_build, stg_test, .post
```

Here is the simplest version of my .gitlab-ci.yml that reproduces the error:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  SAST_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES: "true"

stages:
  - stg_build
  - stg_test
```

I found a similar error in [GitLab: chosen stage does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840199/gitlab-chosen-stage-does-not-exist) but that was about trying to use an environment variable as a stage name.

How do I prevent this error and get SAST working for my merge requests on Gitlab?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the `Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` template expects there to be a stage named `test` but the test stage in .gitlab-ci.yml was renamed "stg_test".

I was able to find two ways to satisfy the CI Lint tool:

1. Rename "stg_test" to "test"
2. Configure the sast script to run during "stg_test" but adding the following to .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
sast:
  stage: stg_test
```

Sources:

1. [gitlab developer community](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292213#note_464880381)
2. [Getting error message sast job: stage parameter should be [some stage name here]](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/#getting-error-message-sast-job-stage-parameter-should-be-some-stage-name-here)